# Is there a way to get a 10000x10000 virtual resolution desktop?

Tags: virtual-machine, screenshot, screen-capture, resolution

I have a java applet map viewer and I'd like to plot out the map it displays. To do that I need to open it in a high enough resolution to avoid too much stitching.

Is there any possible way I could get a desktop with such high resolution?

So far I've been able to use panning 2560x1920 by booting windows 7 in VmWare Player. Would it be possible to get it higher?

Maybe this would be doable on Linux?

The whole thing can be laggy as hell as long as it will render my screenshot...

Comment: Zoom out/downsize then resize? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested Ignacio's suggestion but what I did was run ubuntu in a virtual machine and configure and start a vnc server with:

```
vncserver -geometry 5000x5000
```

Then I used a vncviewer to connect to the server from the host OS. Firefox kept crashing but Chromium worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) can be used to create a virtual display larger than the graphics hardware can support.